# Need My angular app to connect to nodemailer

Tags: angular, express, angular6, nodemailer, angular-universal

I have a website I'm building for the company I work at. It's built in Angular and I've followed instructions from the angular universal Wiki to install express and render my app on the server. The last part I have an issue with is the Contact page. I have the form set to action="/send-email" and method="post", but clicking the submit button does not trigger anything. My inexperienced self is thinking something is not triggering app.post in my Server.ts file. After the past 2 days of mad Googling and scavenging stackoverflow, I'm at a breaking point, I don't know how to move forward. Any guidance is welcomed, thank you in advance!

EDIT:
**My Contact.component.html**

```
<form action="/send-email" method="post">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="to">To:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="to">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="body">Body:</label>
      <textarea cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control" name="body"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</form>
```

UPDATE: My contact.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
selector: 'app-contact',
templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})

export class ContactComponent {
title = 'Angular PHP Email Example!';


constructor() {

}

}
```

My server.ts file (I pulled a lot of this from the Angular wiki, and I use this and turn it into my server.js file per angular universal docs)

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';


// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express(),
nodeMailer = require('nodemailer'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');
// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
});
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//My code for Nodemailer
app.post('/send-email', function (req, res) {
let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: '*****',
        pass: '*****'
    }
});
let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Krunal Lathiya" <xx@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: req.body.to, // list of receivers
    subject: req.body.subject, // Subject line
    text: req.body.body, // plain text body
    html: '<b>NodeJS Email Tutorial</b>' // html body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    res.render('index');
});
});
// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: If you check in your browsers developer tools network panel, is the browser sending the `POST` request when you click submit?

Comment: You didn't made an Angular form but an HTML form. So for now this question is about HTML and express.

Comment: Currently I am not receiving a post request in the network tab.

Comment: While this form is structured as an html form, it is being used in a component that is part of an Angular project. I Edited my question to clarify that and include my contact.component.ts